# How to copy data from string to fields in struct

Tags: c, string, struct

I know this code is sloppy, I'm trying to relearn string manipulation in C. If I have a string `ABBCCCD` and I want to store the separate letters in a struct, is there an efficient way to do so? I have some code down below to demonstrate the long way of what I'm trying to do. (Also, do I have to manually add the null-terminator when I'm doing a `strncpy`?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dst_struct {
    char a[2];
    char b[3];
    char c[4];
    char d[2];
} dst_struct_t;

int main(void) {
    char* test = "ABBCCCD";
    char* src = malloc(strlen(test)+1);
    strncpy(src, test, strlen(test)+1);
    printf("%s\n", src);

    dst_struct_t dst;

    strncpy(dst.a, src,  1);
    strncpy(dst.b, src+1, 2);
    strncpy(dst.c, src+3, 3);
    strncpy(dst.d, src+6, 1);


    printf("dst.a: %s\n", dst.a);
    printf("dst.b: %s\n", dst.b);
    printf("dst.c: %s\n", dst.c);
    printf("dst.d: %s\n", dst.d);

    free(src);


}
```

Comment: Yes, you have to add the null terminator manually.

Comment: Are the letters always at the same offsets, or do you need to dynamically find the runs of similar letters? Your structure definition has the lengths hard-coded.

Comment: `strncpy` will add the null terminator unless the source string is too long to fit the buffer length passed in.  Also, the length argument of `strncpy` should be the size of the destination buffer, not the source buffer.  It is to prevent overflowing the destination in the case that the source string is too long.

Comment: @Barmar, I know the offsets and the lengths are always the same. I.e. Always one "A", two "B"s, etc.

Comment: Although this is a questionable approach in the first place, `char* src = malloc(strlen(test)*sizeof(char));` should be: `char* src = malloc((strlen(test)+1));//+1 is for \0 termination, and sizeof(char) is always 1`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The length has to be less than or equal to the size of the destination. He's setting it to the number of characters to copy, which is always one less than the size of the destination.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: With only a little bit of care, you can use `strncat()` instead of `strncpy()`.  This basically trades manually ensuring termination at a varying position after the copy for manually ensuring termination at a fixed position (often index 0) before the copy.  In this particular case, you could get that initial termination for almost free by providing an initializer for your struct.

Comment: @ryyker he's using `strncpy()` when copying to and from the allocated string, it's not null terminated, so he doesn't need to allocate space for the null.

Comment: But there's not really any need to make a copy of the string in the first place.

Comment: Guidance from the comments should not be edited into your original post, otherwise the it results in new comments chasing never-ending changes withing the post. (exception would be for formatting improvements for readability.)

Comment: after the statement: `dst_struct_t dst;`  there needs to be the statement: `memset( dst, '\0', sizeof( dst ) );`  so there will be a NUL byte terminating any characters in the individual fields of the struct, then you will be able to (successfully) pass each of the fields to `printf()`

Comment: suggest using `memcpy()` rather than `strncpy()` for moving the characters from the literal to the struct

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really any better way to do this, except that you don't need to copy `test` to `src` first.

You also need to add the null terminators to all the strings. It would probably be best to write a function that does both steps: `strncpy()` and adding the null terminator.

```
function copy_n(char *dest, char *src, size_t offset, size_t len) {
    strncpy(src+offset, dest, len);
    dest[len] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
    char* test = "ABBCCCD";

    copy_n(dst.a, test, 0, 1);
    copy_n(dst.b, test, 1, 2);
    copy_n(dst.c, test, 3, 3);
    copy_n(dst.d, test, 6, 1);

    printf("dst.a: %s\n", dst.a);
    printf("dst.b: %s\n", dst.b);
    printf("dst.c: %s\n", dst.c);
    printf("dst.d: %s\n", dst.d);
}
```

Comment: `copy_n(dst.d, test, 6, 1);` results in UB with a short `test` as `src+offset` can, in general, readily access past the end of the string point to by `src`.

Comment: For an assignment I have (which the basis of this question stems off of), I have a struct of 20 members (defining a boot sector header). Do I really have to do this for all 20 members?

Comment: @chux It's up to the programmer to ensure that they don't access out of bounds, just like when using `strncpy()` directly. This is just a way to make a DRY version of the original code.

Comment: @AxelMunoz You could create an array containing all the parameters and loop through it. But there's no way to avoid listing all the structure members, string offsets, and sizes sizes somewhere.

Comment: @AxelMunoz If you didn't want to list all 20 explicitly, a better way would be to make `dst` an array of `char *`, and parse the input string in a loop looking for repeating sequences.

Answer (score 0):

From the `strcpy`/`strncpy` man page:

> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
>
> **char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);**
>
> The  strcpy()  function copies the string pointed to by src, **including the terminating null byte ('\0')**, to the buffer pointed to by dest.  The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.  Beware of buffer overruns!  (See BUGS.)
>
> The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied.  **Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.**

The `n` argument of `strncpy` is generally meant to be the length of the destination buffer, as the point of the function is to be like `strcpy` but prevent overflowing the destination buffer if the source string is too long or not NULL-terminated.  If used in that manner, your destination string will be NULL-terminated if the source string fits that length, otherwise the final byte of the buffer will contain the `n`th character of the source string.

However, the way you seem to be using `strncpy` is to set the exact number of characters you want to copy from the source buffer to place in the destination buffer.  That is not really the intended purpose of `strncpy`.  Instead, what you'd want to use is `memcpy`, since you are really not concerned with the zero-termination of the source string, but rather just copying a set number of characters from a set location.  And yes, you will have to manually add the null-terminator if you use `memcpy`.